# How do I represent a schema diagram of my MongoDB database?

Tags: documentation, uml, nosql, mongodb, diagrams

I have a MongoDB database that I want to properly document its schema design. I know that MongoDB is a NoSQL database and is schemaless by nature, but I do enforce a schema through my application and I want to represent it in a better way than a print of a `findOne()` result.

I see many people using ER or UML, but I don't feel that's conceptually right to represent my NoSQL database as a relational DB or, at least, it looks weird.

Example using UML: [MongoDB: How to represent a schema diagram in a thesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11323841/1476885)

I thought that people would be using different models. I've searched and the far that I've saw was [MongoVUE](http://www.mongovue.com/) that offers a nice Tree view to understand the schema, but its not printer-friendly.

Is there something else that I'm missing for the NoSQL world? Or should I rest and stick with traditional UML?

Answer (score 7):

I would model the schema as a UML class diagram. Class diagrams are not specifically aimed at relational databases, but rather at object oriented environments. In my opinion, MongoDB conceptually matches UML better than a relational database. The [question you refer to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323841/mongodb-how-to-represent-a-schema-diagram-in-a-thesis) provides more information about how to use UML for MongoDB.